# Use to 2 parameters ... in one function

Tags: r, function, ggplot2

I know that the title of question sounds silly but I want to create a function `test_f` which can use several parameters of functions used within `test_f` ( I used latest version of `ggplot2` with new function `aes_` ).
E.g.

```
devtools::install_github('hadley/scales')
devtools::install_github('hadley/ggplot2')

test <- function(data,x,y,...){
  ggplot(data, aes_(substitute(x), substitute(y)))+
    geom_point(...)+
    scale_y_continuous(...)
}
```

When

```
test(mtcars, qsec, mpg,limit = c(1,100))
```

everything works, but

```
test(mtcars, qsec, mpg,size = 5)
```

it shows an error: `Error in scale_y_continuous: Unused parameter (size = 5)`.

I know why it happened but I wonder whether it is any possiblity to use `...` for more than one internal function instead of putting all parameters into `test_f` like below?

```
test <- function(data,x,y,..., size = 5, limit = c(1,100){
   ...
   ...
}
```

Comment: No, ... won't get passed as parameter you have to specify what you want. If you want it changeable just add size and limit as another parameters (with some default value) so if you don't change them they still work

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can, but it just depends on how the receiving functions handle things:

```
f2 <- function(three, ...) {

  g <- as.list(match.call())

  print(sprintf("three (from named args) = %d", three))

  if ("five" %in% names(g)) print(sprintf("five (from ...) = %d", g$five))

}

f1 <- function(x, y, ...) {

  if (missing(x)) stop("x is missing", call.=FALSE)
  if (missing(y)) stop("y is missing", call.=FALSE)

  g <- as.list(match.call())

  print(sprintf("x = %d", x))
  print(sprintf("y = %d", y))

  f2(...)  

}

f1(1, 2, three=4, five=6)
## [1] "x = 1"
## [1] "y = 2"
## [1] "three (from named args) = 4"
## [1] "five (from ...) = 6"
```

Since what you're getting stuck on is `scale_y_continuous` (and, hence, `continuous_scale`) complaining about the unused parameter, you can pass in only what it will accept from the `...` list. It means some internal legwork for your function, but it's definitely doable:

```
mygg <- function(data, x, y, ...) {

  gg <- ggplot(data=data, aes_(substitute(x), substitute(y)))

  # get what geom_point accepts
  geom_point_aes <- c("x", "y", "alpha", "colour", "color", "fill", "shape", "size", "stroke")
  point_params <- unique(c(geom_point_aes, 
                           names(formals(geom_point)), 
                           names(formals(layer))))

  # get what scale_y_continuous accepts
  scale_y_params <- unique(c(names(formals(scale_y_continuous)), 
                             names(formals(continuous_scale))))

  # get all ... params passed in (if any)
  args <- list(...)

  if (length(args) > 0) {

    # get all the arg names
    arg_names <- names(args)

    # which ones are left for point
    gg <- gg + do.call(geom_point, 
                       sapply(intersect(arg_names, point_params), 
                              function(x) { list(args[[x]]) }))

    # which ones are left for scale_y
    gg <- gg + do.call(scale_y_continuous, 
                       sapply(intersect(arg_names, scale_y_params), 
                              function(x) { list(args[[x]]) }))

  } else {

    gg <- gg + geom_point() + scale_y_continuous()

  }

  return(gg)

}
```

I won't clutter up the answer with pngs but if you run the following you should see what the modified function does.

```
mygg(mtcars, mpg, wt)

mygg(mtcars, mpg, wt, color="blue")

mygg(mtcars, mpg, wt, limits=c(3,4))

mygg(mtcars, mpg, wt, fill="green", color="blue", shape=21, limits=c(3,4), left="over")
```

Comment: Wow. Great! Really appreciate it!

Answer (score 1):

it's probably worth mentioning the alternative strategy of using one or two lists to wrap the optional arguments. Borrowing from the other answer,

```
mygg <- function(data, x, y, 
                 geom_pars = list(), 
                 scale_pars = list()) {

  p <- ggplot(data=data, aes_(substitute(x), substitute(y)))
  g <- do.call(geom_point, geom_pars)
  s <- do.call(scale_y_continuous, scale_pars)

  p + list(g, s)

}
```

Calling the function is a bit more verbose, but often less confusing because we're explicit about where the arguments should go.

```
mygg(mtcars, mpg, wt)

mygg(mtcars, mpg, wt, geom_pars=list(color="blue"))

mygg(mtcars, mpg, wt, scale_pars=list(limits=c(3,4)))

mygg(mtcars, mpg, wt, 
    geom_pars=list(fill="green", color="blue", shape=21), 
    scale_pars=list(limits=c(3,4)))
```